# Conditional attributes of github repository in Terraform

Tags: terraform, github-pages, terraform-provider-github

I want to conditionally set arguments to resources when managing Github repositories with Terraform.

I would like to have different pages blocks depending on the value of the has_pages parameter, as in the following example

Example:

```
resource "github_repository" "example" {
  name        = "example"
  description = "My awesome web page"

  private = false

  if ${var.has_page} == true:
    pages {
      source {
        branch = "master"
        path   = "/docs"
      }
    }
  end
}
```

I'm having trouble using dynamic as well!
Does anyone know how to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use a combination of `dynamic` and `for_each`:

```
resource "github_repository" "example" {
  name        = "example"
  description = "My awesome web page"

  private = false

  dynamic "pages" {
    for_each = var.has_page ? [1] : []
    content {
      source {
        branch = "master"
        path   = "/docs"
      }
    }
  }

}
```

More information about how to use `dynamic` is in [1] and about `for_each` is in [2].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each